# Como integrar JavaFX ao SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, javafx, injeção-de-dependência

Estou com o seguinte caso:

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com o Spring Boot, e estou desenvolvendo o front-end com o JavaFX. É uma aplicação local, não web. Eu consigo rodar o projeto, o Spring executa, e a janela preparada com o JavaFX aparece. Porém, ao tentar manipular dados, trazendo eles para que sejam exibidos na janela com o JavaFX, obtenho um erro:

`Cannot invoke "services.ClienteService.findAll()" because "this.cs" is null at com.fgwr.jpcorretora.FrontApp.<init>(FrontApp.java:39)`

Sem o JavaFX a aplicação roda normalmente. Estou executando o JavaFX + Spring Boot da seguinte maneira:

**Classe Spring Boot:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JpcorretoraApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
ClienteService cs;

public JpcorretoraApplication() {
        List <Cliente> allcli = cs.findAll();
        for (Cliente cliente : allcli) {
            clienteData.add(cliente);
            System.out.println(cliente.getNome());
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(FrontApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
```

**Classe javaFX**:

```
public class FrontApp extends Application {
    
    @Autowired
    ClienteService cs;
    
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private ObservableList<Cliente> clienteData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public FrontApp() {
        clienteData = (ObservableList<Cliente>) cs.findAll();
        for (Cliente cliente : clienteData) {
            System.out.println(clienteData);
        }
    }

    public ObservableList<Cliente> getClienteData() {
        return clienteData;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        this.applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(JpcorretoraApplication.class).run(args);
    }
```

Em qualquer uma das classes que eu tento executar o meu serviço `cs`, obtenho o erro. Pelo que já trabalhei no spring boot, pressuponho que seja uma falha de injeção, em que o serviço `cs` não esteja sendo injetado quando tento trabalhar fora do contexto do Spring Boot, ou seja, dentro do javaFx. Tentei várias soluções, porém nenhuma satisfez minha necessidade.

Todas as classes estão com suas respectivas anotações corretas (ex: `@Service`).

A idéia é que eu possa recuperar os dados do meu banco de dados que está sendo operado pelo JPARepository no spring boot e passar para o javafx mostrar na tela. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Ñ sei como funciona mas tente ler isso: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33612130/2241463 Parece que a anotação `@SpringBootApplication` apesar de parecer que seria só para a aplicação principal pode ser que sirva para ser usada em várias aplicações dentro da principal, assim poderia dar para incluir ela na sua classe `FrontApp`. Outra ideia é resolver isso via arquivo de configuração, o SpringBoot não deve estar sabendo que nessa classe `FrontApp` tem coisa para ser injetada, tem que avisar ele de alguma forma. Isso não deve ser problema para a `JpcorretoraApplication` por conta da dita anotação.

Comment: Já tentei essas soluções. Nenhuma funcionou. É como se o SpringBoot isolasse minha classe do JavaFX para que ela não tenha acesso ao ambiente. Não consigo executar nenhum serviço dentro de classes do JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de estudar um pouco, obtive algumas soluções para o problema. A mais simples e funcional para o cenário foi:

1 - Registrar o ApplicationContext no método init da classe main do JavaFX:

**MinhaClasseMainDoJavaFX.java**

```
    @Override
    public void init() {
        ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> initializer = ac -> {

            ac.registerBean(Application.class, () -> MainJavaFX.this);
            ac.registerBean(Parameters.class, this::getParameters);
            ac.registerBean(HostServices.class, this::getHostServices);

        };
        this.applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(MinhaClasseAplicaçãoSpring.class)
                .initializers(initializer).run(getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]));
    }
```

2 - Criar uma classe de injeção de contexto no package raiz:

**SpringContext.java**

```
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    static
    ApplicationContext context;
    
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
        
    }
    
    public static ApplicationContext getAppContext() {
        return context;
     }

}
```

3 - Chamar a classe SpringContext NO MÉTODO QUE DESEJO executar a instanciação do meu serviço dentro do SpringBoot.

**EditClienteController.java**

```
    private void handleOk() {
        if (isInputValid()) {
            
            // Aqui iniciamos o contexto do SpringBoot chamando a class ApplicationContext atribuindo ela a variável context:
            ApplicationContext context = SpringContext.getAppContext();
            
            // Aqui chamamos o serviço do SpringBoot desejado, fazendo com que ele receba a bean clienteRepository vinda do ambiente do SpringBoot: 
            ClienteRepository repo = (ClienteRepository)context.getBean("clienteRepository");
            
            cliente.setNome(nomeField.getText());
            cliente.setEmail(emailField.getText());
            cliente.setDataNascimento(Date.from(dataNascimentoField.getValue().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
            cliente.setCpfOuCnpj(cpfField.getText());
            cliente.setRg(rgField.getText());
            cliente.setEstadoCivil(estadoCivilBox.getValue());
            
            // Aqui, executamos o serviço chamado pela nossa implementação do ApplicationContext:
            repo.save(cliente);
            okClicked = true;
            dialogStage.close();
        }
    }
```

Espero ajudar outros colegas que também estão com esta dificuldade.